# how to out timestamp with jq

Tags: jq

I'm trying to out data with jq request

```
"{\"@timestamp\":\"2019-03-13T00:11:03.123Y\"
```

I'm typing: `cat myfile.txt | jq fromjson.timestamp`

But it's incorrect

Comment: Are you sure this has something to do with jQuery?

Comment: And your key is `@timestamp`, not `timestamp`

Comment: yes, in json format it's looks "@timestamp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipeline you're looking for is

```
jq 'fromjson | .["@timestamp"]'
```

You cannot use the `.foo` syntax to access fields with special characters such as "@".

Comment: Explain pls how out other info: `cat easy.txt | jq 'fromjson."@timestamp" | kubernetes.container | .name, .memory.request.bytes'`  idk but it found info about container in timestamp

Comment: Please ask a new question with *concrete* requirements. Give an example of the input and the output that you expect, because there are lots of ways that one could format this information.